# Align histogram bars - Python

Tags: python, alignment, histogram

I need to center the bars of a histogram.

```
x = array
y = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

num_bins = len(array)
n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins, facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
barWidth=20
x.bar(x, y, width=barWidth, align='center')

plt.show()
```

What I need, is that it looks like the one in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1cNM.png)

I tried almost everything, but still can't go through.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your task, I think it's better to calculate the histogram with NumPy and plot with bat function. Please refer to a following code and see how to use bin_edges.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_samples = 100
num_bins = 10
lb, ub = 0, 10 # lower bound, upper bound

# create samples
y = np.random.random(num_samples) * ub

# caluculate histogram
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(y, num_bins, range=(lb, ub))
width = (bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0])

# plot histogram
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1], hist, align='center', 
        width=width, edgecolor='k', facecolor='green', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(range(num_bins))
plt.xlim([lb-width/2, ub-width/2])

plt.show()
```